# Reformat string with `Regexp`, named captures, and `String#%`

Tags: ruby, regex

Does anyone know a way to directly use a `MatchData` object containing named captures as the input to a String template formatting operation (`%`)?  When I attempt to do so, I get a "positional args mixed with named args" error.

```
s  = "One-Two-Three"
re = /(?<first>.*?)-(?<second>.*?)-(?<third>.*)/
puts "%{second}" % s.match(re)
```

I found other ways to achieve the functional objective (ie by creating an array of the captures in the desired order and using positional templating), but the code is comparatively klunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using string interpolation directly:

```
puts "#{s.match(re)['second']}"
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of it this approach.  I like less that the format string doesn't directly reference the captures by name.  In practice I'll have dozens of captures, where keeping names and index numbers aligned will be a maintenance challenge.

Comment: @JWeite I've updated my answer to use the group name.

Comment: Nice. Simple and consistency between the regex captures and format placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s  = "One-Two-Three"
re = /(?<first>.*?)-(?<second>.*?)-(?<third>.*)/

match = s.match(re)
[match.names.map(&:to_sym), match.captures].transpose.to_h
# => {:first=>"One", :second=>"Two", :third=>"Three"}
```

Comment: Brilliant ninja array processing.  Not an easy grok.  I was hoping there was a way to transform MatchData into a usable hash directly (ie, inline).  This works great though.

Answer (score -1):

For ruby < 2.0 you want to use `Hash[]`:

```
m = s.match re
Hash[m.names.map(&:to_sym).zip m.captures]
#=> {:first=>"One", :second=>"Two", :third=>"Three"}
```

Comment: That is called plagiarism.

Comment: It was useful to me, though, to see the <2.0 method of converting an array into a hash.